# Flutter :- Change output on page based on button

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I've made an app that's got a row of three buttons that when pressed are supposed to:
1) turn bold
2) change the output on the page

[image: "Notifications", "Your recipes", "Favorites" are supposed to become bolded when pressed and "output text here changed"]

I've solved step 1 by doing this:

The page's class has an instance variable:

```
  List<bool> _boldButtons = [false, true, false];
```

Each button's TextStyle has the fontWeight property:

```
  fontWeight: _boldButtons[0] ? FontWeight.bold : FontWeight.normal),
```

And its onPresed:

```
onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        _boldButtons = [true, false, false];
                      });
```

This feels hacky, but does the trick. If anyone has a better way of doing this I'd be more then happy to hear!

To solve problem 2) I'm thinking of doing something like this:

Make three methods (notifications(), yourRecipes(), favorites() ) that return a Container. 
Have an instance variable in the page's class that is of that type:

`Container wallOfText;`

In each button's onPressed we set the wallOfText variable to be equal to that button's function, something like this:

```
onPressed: () {
                      wallOfText =  boldButtons[0] ? wallOfText : notifications();
                      // ternary operator to check if we've already selected the button we're pressing, and therefore don't need to redefine what to display

                      setState(() {
                        _boldButtons = [true, false, false];
                      });
```

Then we display the wallOfText variable in the Scaffold.

This also feels really hacky, but might work. Is there a more general way of doing this?

Comment: Do you need to change the button text font family and text on the center of the screen ?

Comment: Yes, I want to change both.

Comment: Ok, Give me time, trying to aceho=ice it

Comment: If it's any help here is my code: https://codeshare.io/GARnWx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have changed little bit in your code, like i have take single variable which hold the selected tab value and update it on tab selection, have a look on below code for it.

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    // TODO: implement createState
    return _HomeScreen();
  }
}

class _HomeScreen extends State<HomeScreen> {
  var selectedTab = 1;
  var selectedText="First Tab";

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build


    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Home"),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              color: Colors.deepOrange,

              child:Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: <Widget>[
                  FlatButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        selectedTab=1;
                        selectedText="First Tab";
                      });

                    },
                    child: Text(
                      "Notifications",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight:
                          selectedTab == 1 ? FontWeight.bold : FontWeight.normal),
                    ),
                  ),
                  FlatButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        selectedTab=2;
                        selectedText="Second Tab";
                      });

                    },
                    child: Text(
                      "Your recipe",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight:
                          selectedTab == 2 ? FontWeight.bold : FontWeight.normal),
                    ),
                  ),
                  FlatButton(
                    onPressed: () {

                      setState(() {
                        selectedTab=3;
                        selectedText="Third Tab";
                      });
                    },
                    child: Text(
                      "Favorites",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight:
                          selectedTab == 3 ? FontWeight.bold : FontWeight.normal),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ) ,
            )
            ,

            Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.6,
              child:  Align(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: Text(selectedText),
              ),
            )


          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And please check the output of it

[image]